# ld: library 'System' not found for assembly

Tags: macos, assembly, linker, nasm, ld

I am trying to write assembly on macos sonoma 14.3 on a 2020 intel macbook pro and it keeps giving me this error.
my code:

```
section .data
    msg: db "hello", 10
section .text
    global _main
_main:
    mov      rax, 0x02000004
    mov      rdi, 1
    mov      rsi, msg
    mov      rdx, 6
    syscall

    mov      rax, 0x02000001
    xor      rdi, rdi
    syscall
```

and i run these in the terminal.

```
nasm -f macho64 test.asm


ld test.o -o test -macos_version_min 14.3 -lSystem
```

I have command line tools installeed, when i try again:
xcode-select: note: Command line tools are already installed. Use "Software Update" in System Settings or the softwareupdate command line interface to install updates(and there are no updates in software updates)

i have tried adding stuff to path from multiple recources:

my .zshrc:

`export LIBRARY_PATH="$LIBRARY_PATH:/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib"`

my .zprofile:

`export SDKROOT=$(xcrun --sdk macosx --show-sdk-path) export LIBRARY_PATH="$LIBRARY_PATH:$SDKROOT/usr/lib"`

my .profile:

`export SDKROOT=$(xcrun --sdk macosx --show-sdk-path) export LIBRARY_PATH="$LIBRARY_PATH:$SDKROOT/usr/lib"`

and in my .bash_profile i have both commands

i have xcode installed. i dont know if i need anything else, didnt find any other idea on the internet

Comment: What error does the ```linker``` give? Show it here.

Comment: it only gives what i put in the title:
ld: library 'System' not found

Comment: Running ```ld --help``` shows two flags ```-L``` and ```-l``` as follows: ```-l LIBNAME Search for library LIBNAME
  -L DIRECTORY Add DIRECTORY to library search path```. Please make a test with both ```-L``` and ```-l``` to provide library ```path``` and ```file```, respectively.

Comment: when i try it with capital L:
szaszdominik@Szaszs-MacBook-Pro boredOS % ld test.o -o test -macos_version_min 14.3 -LSystem

ld: warning: search path 'System' not found
ld: warning: no platform load command found in '/Users/szaszdominik/programming/boredOS/test.o', assuming: macOS
ld: warning: pointer not aligned at _main+0xC from /Users/szaszdominik/programming/boredOS/test.o

Comment: solved it. the problem was with _main or _start. mac does not like that. then i ran using the following commands:
nasm -fmacho64 test.s && ld -static test.o -o test && ./test